# Synchronizing data in tables in two different schemas in an Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have an `attendance table` in one Oracle schema named `attendance_database` and another schema named `payroll_database` and its table name is `payroll_attendance_table`.

Is it possible if I insert new data in `attendance_table` then `payroll_attendance_table` auto synchronize (auto insert/update) with that new inserted data. I hear it can be done by a trigger. Is it, else is there any other way. I want to handle this in database end, not want to handle this by any back-end language.

Comment: you should think in using Materialized view for this scenario, better than triggers. Check this answer to give you an idea how https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280854/create-fast-refresh-mv-over-dblink-on-table-without-pk/280859#280859

Comment: You definitely need a trigger.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai, a trigger is an option, but it can be done using Materialized views with fast refresh on commit.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai is it possible trigger  an event from one database that make action on other database, or trigger event apply only to same database

Comment: Are you sure that you mean "database" here and not "schema"?  You say in a comment to another answer that you have both databases on the same server which implies that you may actually have two different schemas (an Oracle schema is roughly equivalent to what most other database engines call a database).  Or are these both PDBs in the same CDB (assuming a recent version of Oracle)?

Comment: @JustinCave you are right. I mean here two schema instead two database on perspective Oracle

Comment: OK.  I updated the question to reflect that since it significantly impacts the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Create a database link from `attendance_database` to `payroll_database`.
2. Create a row-level trigger on `attendance_database.attendance_table` to `INSERT` new rows across the database link into the `payroll_database.payroll_attendance_table`.

Or:

1. Create a database link from `payroll_database` to `attendance_database`.
2. Create `payroll_attendance_table` as a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` with `FAST REFRESH ON COMMIT` of `attendance_database.attendance_table` across the database link.

Comment: @MTO can you explain the way how can I create the link on two different database table and also explain the trigger code if possible. I have the two database in same server with one dedicated IP address.

Answer (score 1):

First, since the data is just in two different schemas, are you sure you really need to copy it from one to the other?  If `attendance_database.attendance_table` and `payroll_database.payroll_attendance_table` are supposed to have the same data, it would make vastly more sense to eliminate one and just create a synonym in `payroll_database` that points to `attendance_database`.

```
grant select on attendance_database.attendance_table
   to payroll_database;

create synonym payroll_database.payroll_attendance_table
   for attendance_database.attendance_table;
```

If they are not supposed to have the same data (perhaps the `payroll_database.payroll_attendance_table` table is supposed to have additional attributes, for example), you'd most likely want to make `payroll_database.payroll_attendance_table` a child table.  Something like

```
grant references on attendance_database.attendance_table
   to payroll_database;

create table payroll_database.payroll_attendance_table (
  attendance_id integer references attendance_database.attendance_table( attendance_id ),
  <<additional attributes>>
);
```

If you really, really want to have two separate copies of the same data and to maintain them via a trigger, you could do something like

```
create or replace trigger trg_pointless_sync
  before insert or update or delete on attendance_database.attendance_table
  for each row
declare
begin
  if inserting 
  then
    insert into payroll_database.payroll_attendance_table( attendance_id,
                                                           col1,
                                                           col2,
                                                           ...
                                                           colN )
      values( :new.attendance_id,
              :new.col1,
              :new.col2,
              ...,
              :new.colN );
  elsif updating
  then 
    update payroll_database.payroll_attendance_table
       set col1 = :new.col1,
           col2 = :new.col2,
           ...
           colN = :new.colN
     where attendance_id = :new.attendance_id;
  else
    delete from payroll_database.payroll_attendance_table
     where attendance_id = :new.attendance_id;
  end if;
end;
```

Of course, trigger based solutions are usually somewhat problematic.  They can impose pretty significant performance penalties by transforming nice, fast set-based operations on the source table into recursive row-by-row operations.  They can create maintenance issues if, say, a DBA wants to quickly restore `attendance_table` back to a previous state because someone goofed on some data and doesn't realize that deleting all the data has the side-effect of deleting all the data from the `payroll_database` table.  And they almost always create synchronization issues-- what happens if someone modifies one of the rows in `payroll_database`, for example?  Or if someone updates the PK of `attendance_table`, the trigger I wrote isn't smart enough to handle that correctly (you could extend it, of course, but there are usually more of these sorts of corner cases than you're likely to code for) so the two tables will eventually be not-quite-in-sync.